# This one came to me out of nowhere

Tags: riddle, visual

Can you guess the word from the following images?

[image: line]

[image: cell]

[image: cold]

[image: can]

[image: mcguire]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Could the answer be

> Thin

The images represent

> [Thin blue line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_Blue_Line)
>  Blood thinner
>  On Thin ice
>  Thin Air (can of pressurised air)
>  [Thin Lizzy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_Lizzy)  - Thanks due to *Mike Limburg* this pic is from Lizzie Maguire (The Movie)

The title came to you

> Out of thin air

Comment: Nicely found Tom! +1

Comment: Thanks Mike - also for your first image description which was likely a spark!

Comment: Correct.  Good work!

Answer (score 5):

What we got;

> 1. Blue thick line?
>  2. Red blood cell
>  3. Ice cubes
>  4. Dust remover
>  5. Lizzie McGuire

Perhaps a movie?

> [The thin blue line (1988)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096257/)
>  [Blood (2012)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2078552/)
>  [Ice (2017)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5748106/)
>  [Dust (2012)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1220626/)
>  [Lizzie McGuire, The Movie (2003)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0306841/)

Title:

> [Out of Nowhere (2013)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2811750/)

Comment: Interesting but not what I was going for.